# Why does this not work? Am i on the right track?

Tags: html

why doesnt this work? This is my program to "getTutorNames" method. The full problem is in the link. this is only part of the program. Can someone help? I've been stucked for hours. For an example here one of my error message: PeerTutoringReport.java:30: error: variable nameList is already defined in method getTutorNames()
                    Return nameList;
                           ^

Comment: Looks like `Return` should be `return` - right now it thinks you're trying to declare a variable `nameList` of type `Return`.

Comment: There are lot of syntantical errors, Are you using any IDE for development

Comment: There is no property of method called `isNullorEmpty ` for `String`

Comment: What are yout trying to say in this question? Your problem is unclear as well as this question is not much explainatory

Comment: im trying to figure out if im on the right path.... i posted the question in the link. i created a getTutorName method

Comment: and sorry english is very bad.

Comment: Angie: Please do not edit the content of the question out just because you found a solution. Stack Overflow is here to have a repository of questions and answers to help others who come here later.

Comment: Vague title is not going to be useful to future visitors to this site.

Answer (score 1):

There were multiple problems with the method like I said in the comments section

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PeerTutoringReport {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> tutorNames = getTutorNames();
        // sortTutorNames();
        // getTutorDegree();
        // getAmountOfStudentsForTutors();
        // calculateStipend();
        // displayResults();
    }

    private static boolean isNullorEmpty(String s) {
        return s == null || s.matches("\\s*");
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getTutorNames() {

        ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (nameList.size() < 9) {
            String firstName = JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("Enter Tutor First Name: ");
            String lastName = JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("Enter Tutor Last Name: ");

            if (isNullorEmpty(firstName) && isNullorEmpty(lastName)) {
                continue;
            }
            nameList.add(lastName + "," + firstName);
        }
        return nameList;

    }
}
```

Comment: ----jGRASP exec: javac -g PeerTutoringReport.java

PeerTutoringReport.java:31: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
1 error

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.

Comment: i get that one error, but i can not find it.

Comment: Can you share the complete class instead of the method

Comment: import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PeerTutoringReport {

 public static void main(String [] args) {

  ArrayList<String> tutorNames = getTutorNames();
  //sortTutorNames();
  //getTutorDegree();
  //getAmountOfStudentsForTutors();
  //calculateStipend();
  //displayResults();
 }
that is what i have so far plus the method i posted

Comment: @AngieMckenzie Instead of posting it as a comment, edit your question

Comment: there i think, i did it. sorry first time using this haha

Comment: @AngieMckenzie find the update

Comment: if i were to change if (isNullorEmpty(firstName) && isNullorEmpty(lastName) method? how would i do that to fit this prograM? like this IF name == blank THEN
   Return;
  ENDIF
  IF name not valid THEN
   Display error
   Continue; (Jump to top of loop)

Comment: i have not learn this, so i dont want to use it. 
    private static boolean isNullorEmpty(String s) {
        return s == null || s.matches("\\s*");

Comment: is there anyway to end the loop until one of the two possible conditions are met which is  "already having 10 tutors or the users wants  to move on? and THANK YOU!! btw